# How to merge two class in PHP?

Tags: php, class

So that the final class have all member variables/methods in both class

Is there an easy way to go?

Answer (score 13):

You should encapsulate the both classes in a containing class, and provide a relevant interface (such as setters/getters for private variables

```
class YourFirstClass {
   public $variable;
   private $_variable2;
   public function setVariable2($a) {
       $this->_variable2 = $a;
   }
}

class YourSecondClass {
   public $variable;
   private $_variable2;
   public function setVariable2($a) {
       $this->_variable2 = $a;
   }
}

class ContaingClass {
   private $_first;
   private $_second;
   public function __construct(YourFirstClass $first, YourSecondClass $second) {
       $this->_first = $first;
       $this->_second = $second;
   }
   public function doSomething($aa) {
       $this->_first->setVariable2($aa);
   }
}
```

Research (google): "composition over inheritance"

Footnote: sorry for non-creative variable names..

Comment: @user198729: Considering your "at runtime" requirement, do you really mean to merge two *classes*, or did you mean to say two *objects*?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to do this at runtime, or at programming time?
I will assume runtime, in which case what is wrong with using class [inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)? 
Create a new class which inherits from the two you want to merge.

Comment: Not downvoting, but PHP does not (afaik) support multiple inheritance.

Comment: This won't give you access to the private members of the inherited classes.

Comment: yes, sorry, PHP does not support multiple inheritance. However, by stacking the classes to inherit from one or the other, you can emulate multiple inheritance.
private members won't be inherited, yes. But if this is a problem, it is not particularly difficult to change their protection to public (We shall not get started about on a debate about whether private is really needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Merge only properties that are shared between the two classes into this object.
public function conservativeMerge($objectToMerge)
{
    # Makes sure the argument is an object.
    if(!is_object($objectToMerge))
        return FALSE;

    # Used $this to make sure that only known properties in this class are shared.
    # Note: You can only iterate over an object as of 5.3.0 or greater.
    foreach ($this as $property => $value)
    {
        # Makes sure that the mering object has this property.
        if (isset($objectToMerge->$property))
        {
            $objectToMerge->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}


# Merge all $objectToMerge's properties to this object.
public function liberalMerge($objectToMerge)
{
    # Makes sure the argument is an object.
    if(!is_object($objectToMerge))
        return FALSE;

    # Note: You can only iterate over an object as of 5.3.0 or greater.
    foreach ($objectToMerge as $property => $value)
    {
        $objectToMerge->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

You should consider the first method as if it where the object counterpart of [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Then consider the second method as if it where the object counterpart for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).